# Selenium for Python is not inputting fields

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get Selenium with Python to auto login to this website, but it leaves the fields blank.  I have tried to use ID's as well but it doesn't work.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

username = "lambda@gmail.com"
password = "noWayJose"

url = "https://squareup.com/login"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name("sign_in_button").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within the *Email address* and *Password* *`<input>`* fields you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://squareup.com/login')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email"))).send_keys("lambda@gmail.com")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password").send_keys("noWayJose")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://squareup.com/login')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']"))).send_keys("lambda@gmail.com")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']").send_keys("noWayJose")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: squareup]

Comment: Great!  Now how do I get it to click the Sign In button?

Comment: Glad to be able to help you. _"how do I get it to click the Sign In button"_ sounds to be a different question altogether. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in this but for your information, After clicking the signin button there is a captcha. You can automate that using any captcha solving API like 2captcha or anycaptcha.

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = "lambda@gmail.com"
password = "noWayJose"

url = "https://squareup.com/login"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")

driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//market-button[@id='login-standard-submit']").click()
```