# Selenium how to locate all elements with the tag h2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello so given that i have navigated to this site

https://uk.trustpilot.com/categories

I would like to retrieve the headings of each catogory by using inspect element, I noticed that every heading of the catorgories has a h2 tag

[image]

My thoughts were to use a EC condition to wait till for the visibility of all elements that have a h2 tag which should return a list containing all h2 tags which i can then just call getattribute(text) on to get the text

```
def select_catogory(self):
        list = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h2')))
        print(len(list))
        catogories = self.driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,value ="h2")
        for cat in catogories:
            print(cat.get_attribute('text')
```

both presence_of_all_elements_located returned nothing and same with find_elements

)

I realised that my main issue was in my loop where i never had a break condition so it was giving a stale element warning, which i thought was caused by this function, Thanks for the help

```
def select_button_by_name(self, name_of_button: str):
        """
        Navigates to the button in question and clicks on it

        input: name_of_button (string)
        """
        self.wait
       
        buttons_by_href = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,value ="//a[@href]") #finds all the href tags on the webpage
        for button in buttons_by_href:
           # Matches the attribute text to the provided button string
            if button.get_attribute("text") == name_of_button:
                #clicks on the button
                button.click()
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) solution worked:

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `python` or `pytest`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__, "-s")

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_base(self):
        self.open("https://uk.trustpilot.com/categories")
        h2_elements = self.find_visible_elements("h2")
        print()
        for element in h2_elements:
            print(element.text.strip())
```

Output was:

```
Animals & Pets
Beauty & Well-being
Business Services
Construction & Manufacturing
Education & Training
Electronics & Technology
Events & Entertainment
Food, Beverages & Tobacco
Health & Medical
Hobbies & Crafts
Home & Garden
Home Services
Legal Services & Government
Media & Publishing
Money & Insurance
Public & Local Services
Restaurants & Bars
Shopping & Fashion
Sports
Travel & Vacation
Utilities
Vehicles & Transportation
```

Comment: Yeah it worked for me i was being a idiot, in my previous step I had a button click within a for loop which i never exited out of so it was giving a stale element error, i fixed it by breaking out of the loop

Comment: Instead of text, all the attributes with 'data', how it would be? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the headings of each catogory using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) in a single line of code inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://uk.trustpilot.com/categories')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("textContent") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2[class^='typography_heading']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://uk.trustpilot.com/categories')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Animals & Pets', 'Beauty & Well-being', 'Business Services', 'Construction & Manufacturing', 'Education & Training', 'Electronics & Technology', 'Events & Entertainment', 'Food, Beverages & Tobacco', 'Health & Medical', 'Hobbies & Crafts', 'Home & Garden', 'Home Services', 'Legal Services & Government', 'Media & Publishing', 'Money & Insurance', 'Public & Local Services', 'Restaurants & Bars', 'Shopping & Fashion', 'Sports', 'Travel & Vacation', 'Utilities', 'Vehicles & Transportation']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```