# TimeoutException error using wedrivier.wait in Selenium logging within glassdoor.co.in

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am going to scrap Glassdoor to extract companies' reviews! for the 1st step, I need to log in to extract all reviews, I put a time.sleep and wait time for clicking the "Singing" button, but I have still the following error:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) TimeoutException
```

My code is like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pandas as pd  
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver_path= r"C:\Users\TMaghsoudi\Desktop\chromedriver_win32.exe"
# chrome options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
Pros =[]
Cons=[]
Re_Titles =[]
Re_rates= []
Employ_status= []
Re_dates = []

# set driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)
# get url
url = "https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Job/index.htm"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "HeaderStyles__signInButton").click()
time.sleep(5)
Enter_email= driver.find_element(By.ID, "modalUserEmail")
Enter_email.send_keys("XXXXX")
Enter_email.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
Enter_pass= driver.find_element(By.ID,"modalUserPassword")
Enter_pass.send_keys("XXXX")
time.sleep(3)
# SingIn= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='d-flex align-items-center flex-column']/button[@class='gd-ui-button mt-std minWidthBtn css-1dqhu4c evpplnh0']")))
SingIn= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "evpplnh1")))
SingIn.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the *`Email`* and *`Password`* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Job/index.htm")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.d-lg-block button.HeaderStyles__signInButton"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#modalUserEmail"))).send_keys(email + Keys.RETURN)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#modalUserPassword"))).send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: glassdoor]

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I have tried your commands, but the error still exists! Now I see the error when the code is going to click the "SingIn" Link (the 1st line of your code)! Even I changed the waiting-time to 10, but it doesn't work!