# XPATH cannot locate element with colon in its ID or name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am on a side project to write python script to auto-login a website.

I am trying to use python script to launch FireFox browser and auto-login into a website

Below is the source code of the element i'm trying to locate:
[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SIjg.png)
I used below

```
item_email= WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,'username')]")))
```

or below

```
item_email= WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,'username')]")))
```

or below

```
item_email = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='j_id0:j_id5:loginComponent:loginForm:username']")))
```

They all ended up with selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

I was able to locate elements when the input ID didn't have colons (not with namespace, i guess)

Comment: yeah explicit wait will always end up in `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` exception if the element is not found in HTMLDOM.

Answer (score 0):

erhai950,

**Explicit wait** will always end up in `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` exception if the element is not found in HTMLDOM for any reason.

You can try the below xpath:

```
//input[contains(@id,'username') and @placeholder='Email']
```

Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  and see `//input[contains(@id,'username') and @placeholder='Email']` if your desired element is getting highlighted or not.

Now if we have 1/1 matching entry then try below code:

```
item_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,'username') and @placeholder='Email']")
```

or

```
item_email= WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,'username') and @placeholder='Email']")))
```

Also check if this web element is in iframe or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately I am still unable to get it work. It looks like it's due to the website developed using Angular and will redirect to a different URL the XPATH won't work. Using the similar XPATH worked before the website updated. I guess I have have to use a different method than XPATH

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

the element is a `<input>` element which would accept text input.

---

### Solution

Ideally to send a *character sequence* to an `<input>` element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.form-group input[id$='username'][name$='username'][placeholder='Email']"))).send_keys("erhai950")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-group']//input[contains(@id, 'username') and contains(@name, 'username')][@placeholder='Email']"))).send_keys("erhai950")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately I am still unable to get it work. It looks like it's due to the website developed using Angular and will redirect to a different URL the XPATH won't work. Using the similar XPATH worked before the website updated. I guess I have have to use a different method than XPATH

Comment: @erhai950 Update the question with the error you observe with this code suggested in this answer.