# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'username' at selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots

im trying to learn "Selenium" but i have a mistake in my codes but i cant find it. I imported some variable other file like that " from githubuser import username,password ". im trying to auto github signer but i cant :( can u help me ?

`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from githubuser import username, password

class Github:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.username = username    
        self.password = password
    def signin(self):
        self.browser.get("https://github.com/login/")
        time.sleep(2)
        self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login_field"]').username.send_keys(self.username) 
        self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]').password.send_keys(self.password)

        time.sleep(2)
        self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login"]/div[4]/form/div/input[11]').click()

github = Github(username = username, password = password)
github.signin()
```

`

Comment: Add more information, and specify your objective better.

Comment: Also maybe have a look at playwright, which is the more modern version of what selenium was created for way back when. It's not Python, but it's a _lot_ better than Selenium.

Comment: Try removing `.username` from `self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login_field"]').username.send_keys(self.username)`. Try with `self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="login_field"]').send_keys(self.username)`, Similarly do for the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Username* and *Password* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://github.com/login/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#login_field"))).send_keys(username)
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#password").send_keys(password)
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='commit']").click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```