# Problem with login to a journal website with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, data-science

I ran this code to login into website of journals with my institutional access:

```
import pandas as pd


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

import time
import os



output = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\97254\\Downloads\\output.xlsx")

url = "https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/nvpp20"




driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"sign-in-link").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element("tag name","a").find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="frmLogin"]/div[2]/ul/li/a').click()
time.sleep(3)
elem = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="shibboleth_search"]/div/input').send_keys("Bar-Ilan University")
```

but google chrome didn't pass me to the identification by password screen. I got kicked out of website , with this output on python :[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww9PD.png). has this occured because I used undetected_chromedriver library? How do I handle this to move on to password identification screen?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WebDriverWait`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) instead of sleep. Also, use [`By.TAG_NAME`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) or `By.CSS_SELECTOR` to find element(s). And you need to use `driver.forward()` to use changed document page.
And instead of loading home page, just to click on button which directs you to login page, why not directly go to login page.

```
...
# importing action chains to scroll to element
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
actions = ActionChains(driver)

...
# waiting till email_field appears
email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"sign-in-link")))
actions.move_to_element(email_field).perform()
email_field.send_keys("my@email.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"password"))).send_keys("mypassword")
submit_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"submit")))
# scrolling to submit button just in case it isn't in view
actions.move_to_element(submit_btn).perform()
submit_btn.click()
# telling driver to use new page loaded after submitting
driver.forward()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447), [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) to send a *character sequence* within the ***Select your institution*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/nvpp20")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#cookie-accept"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "sign-in-link"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Log in via your institution']//following-sibling::div[2]//a"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Type the name of your institution']"))).send_keys("Bar-Ilan University")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```