# How to locate the input element within nested divs using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm having trouble locating element `<input class='search-text'...>` and would like to place the text 'hello' into the text box.

[Trying to locate the input class='search-text'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Annn9.png)

My webdriver code is the following

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='filter-panel']//li[@class='filter-selection']//filter-selector//div[@class=filter-component]//div//div[@class='search-box-wrapper']/input[@class='search-text']").send_keys("hello")
```

That results in:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='filter-panel']//li[@class='filter-selection']//filter-selector//div[@class=filter-component]//div//div[@class='search-box-wrapper']/input[@class='search-text']"}
```

I was hoping the word "hello" would be placed in the Search... box.

HTML snapshot of the *Search...* input box:

[image: I'm trying to locate the Search... input box]

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) which explicitly and in **bold and ALL CAPS** tell you not to post images of text (which includes not posting links to images of text). Put _the text_ in your post. On a different note: why use xpath when you're working with web pages? Why not just run a queryselect inside the document you loaded?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the html:

[image: html]

the desired element is a dynamic element.

---

### Solution

Ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.search-text[aria-label='Enter text for search by keyword']"))).send_keys("yummybagels")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='search-text' and @aria-label='Enter text for search by keyword']"))).send_keys("yummybagels")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```